# create a zip code value to points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, raster-conversion, zip-codes

I have a shapefile of points (samples collection locations) with their `longitude and latitude` and the number of samples collected in each location.
My goal is to create a raster of the number of samples collected per zip-code.
Unfortunately my shapefile doesn't include zip code information.

Is there a way to get the zip code for every sample collection location? I was also thinking maybe there is a way to have that shapefile on top of a US zipped basemap and combine both?

Answer (score 3):

From TIGER: ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/ZCTA5/

This is a shapefile of every ZIP code from the most recent update.

You can spatial join your shapefile of points to the shapefile of ZIP polygons.

Comment: This is great I will work on it and let you know, thanks

Comment: it's going really slow though ...

Comment: the spatial join should yield the results you need

Comment: Intersecting the zip code boundaries and points would also work (providing a zip attribute for each point).